# xively java client returns status code 401

Tags: java, eclipse, xively

Trying to learn the Java interface to Xively.  The following simple test fails with a 401 status code:

```
Feed myFeed = XivelyService.instance().feed().get(2126903832);
```

The exception statement is

> com.xively.client.http.exception.HttpException: Http response status
>   indicates unsuccessful operation[Status code: 401.; Reason:
>   {"title":"Unauthorized","errors":"You do not have permission to access
>   this resource"} ]

The following console line leads me to believe that I'm not setting up the API key correctly:

> 2013-10-21 18:58:17,925 506   DEBUG [DefaultClientConnection.java:
>   276] (main:) >> X-ApiKey:

The Developer docs says replace `<your api key>` in `config.properties` with my API key. I did that, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I installed the library with Maven to my default Maven repo and point to it in Referenced Libraries.  I am trying to build the whole thing in Eclipse.

My specific question is where is the `config.properties` the ApiConfig is reading?

Comment: The best way to find out would be adding a few `println()` in [`AppConfig#loadProperties()`](https://github.com/xively/Xively4J/blob/e2347ba/src/main/java/com/xively/client/AppConfig.java#L78)

Comment: Actually, all you need is one `println(fileName);` just outside the `if/else` block on line 89...

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I added the println and got: C:/Users/<User>/.m2/repository/com/xively/client/xively-java-client/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/xively-java-client-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jarconfig.properties

After adding the API key for the feed to that file I see the API key in the console but get precisely the same 401 result.

I even generated a master key and tried it, but also the same result. 

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should report at https://github.com/xively/Xively4J/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.  The problem was that I had double quotes in the config.properties file.  The line should read:

```
api.key=yWYxyi3HpdqFCBtKHueTvOGoGROSAKxGRFAyQWk5d3JNdz0g
```